# send cookies with urlconnection

Tags: java, cookies, steam

I'm trying to login to Steam with cookies. Tried 2 ways, first is:

```
URL url = new URL("https://steamcommunity.com/");

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
CookieStore cookieStore = cookieManager.getCookieStore();

HttpCookie steamAuthCookie = new HttpCookie("steamMachineAuth*****************", "SteamMachineAuthValue");
steamAuthCookie.setDomain(".steamcommunity.com");
steamAuthCookie.setPath("/");

HttpCookie steamLogin = new HttpCookie("steamLogin", "SteamLoginCookieValue");
steamLogin.setDomain(".steamcommunity.com");
steamLogin.setPath("/");

cookieStore.add(new URI("https://steamcommunity.com/"), steamAuthCookie);
        cookieStore.add(new URI("https://steamcommunity.com/"), steamLogin);

URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
urlConnection.connect();
urlConnection.getContent();
```

Doesn't work, Steam still offer me to login
I thought that URLConnection doesn't support CookieManager, so I found and tried second way:

```
URL url = new URL("https://steamcommunity.com/");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.8");

String cookie = "steamMachineAuth*****************=****************************************;steamLogin=**************************************************************";
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);

urlConnection.connect();
urlConnection.getContent();
```

And still steam offers me to login.
Stuck with it, don't know even how to check - whether cookies sent or not.
What's the right way to send cookies?

Comment: You may need to set more than just that one cookie.  My browser shows 12 cookies for steamcommunity.com, including both `steamLogin` and `steamLoginSecure`.

Comment: I know that to correct login I must have 2 cookies - steamLogin and SteamMachineAuth. Tested it in Chrome - deleted everything except these two - steam recognized me, deleted steamLogin or SteamMachineAuth - steam asked me for login.

Answer (score 0):

Install a network sniffer like Wireshark, login manually to steam in your browser and analyze the sent data. Compare it with the data sent by your java program, byte after byte.

Comment: Thanks, will do it if no other solution will be found.